# Why do microservices need to communicate with each other?

Tags: events, microservices

I'm new with this but in case if we have fronted + few different microservices I just don't get why do we need any of them to communicate with each other if we can manipulate between their data via axios on frontend. What is the purpose of event bus and event-driven architecture in the case if we use both frontend and backend microservices?

Okay, for my example I'm using 5 microservices. There are 2 of them:

- Shopping cart
- Posts

And I want to access posts microservice directly, pass their data through the event bus, so the shopping cart microservice would have its information. The reason is that posts and shopping cart both have different data bases, so is a good example doing this that way, or just through frontend with axios service?

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting could be true for a very simple application, which hardly even needs an architecture such as microservice. It is clear why services need communication:

1. some services are not even accessable (for various reasons such as security) in client, so a change in them must be initiated in other backend services with such priviledge
2. some changes are raised in backend services and not client, e.g. a cronjob for doing some task
3. it would question reusability as you must consider the service to be used by not only client, but in any environment
4. what would happen if you want your services to be used by public, what if they do not implement part of the needed logic intentionally or by mistake
5. making client do everything could be so complex and would reduce flexibility
6. some services such as authentication are acting as a supporting mechanism to ensure safety (or anything other than main logic), these should be communicated directly by the service needing them

As for second part of your question, it depends on several factors like your business needs & models, desired scalability, performance, availability, etc. so the right answer or in another say, the answer that fits would be different.

For your problem, using event bus which is async would not be a good solution as it would hurt consistency in your services. Instead synchronous ways like a simple API call in your `posts service` would be a better idea.

Comment: That makes sense.. So I'm making a project which has to include microservice architecture, and those microservices have to communicate with each other (at least one with another), so I updated my question, can you take a review and update your answer? I would be thankful.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, maybe it doesn't seem like a more complex application but my whole application has to contain asynchronous ways, like one microservice communicating with another, so is this a good example in this case with those 2 microservices
or is their use in this way completely unnecessary? Should I try doing this with different microservices?

Comment: I'm not sure I know the main difference between async and synchronous calls, but can two microservices communicate synchronously?

Comment: You could still use event bus for different parts of your application, but for this matter, I do not suggest it as it makes harder to ensure consistency (meaning e.g. a data in `posts` has changed, but the change has not been occured in `shopping carts` when you call some other related API).

Comment: Yes, they surely can. I suggest reading this article for more information on the communication types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me alot, can you give a real good example in an answer when to use Event Bus? For example I have: Post service, comment service, cart service, payment service and user service. Just a theoretical recommendation if you don’t mind.

Comment: Thank you! I will look at it

Comment: In general, if consistency is not an issue, using asynchronous ways are more advantagous, as it would loosen coupling, enhance performance of each API call (as there is no waiting for answer), bring more reliability & scalability to platforms with many services (though still it matters how services are designed).

Comment: Can you also give me a code example of synchronous microservices call? I can't find it anywhere